# Saving to db with devMode true works, but not when false

Tags: plugin-development, mysql

```
// Upload and save as temp file
$request = Craft::$app->request;
$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
$tempPath = $file->saveAsTempFile();

// Create as permanent asset
$folder = Craft::$app->getAssets()->findFolder(['id' => 5]);
$asset = new Asset();
$asset->tempFilePath = $tempPath;
$asset->filename = Assets::prepareAssetName($file->name);
$asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
$asset->volumeId = $folder->volumeId;
$asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
$asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);

// Save ticket to db
$ticket = new ErrorReportingRecord();
$ticket->description = $description;
...
$ticket->assetId = $asset->id;
...
$ticket->save();
```

The problem is `$ticket->assetId = $asset->id;`. When `devMode` is `true` the asset id is stored in the db table as expected (`assetId int(11) DEFAULT NULL`). But when `devMode` is `false` the value of `assetId` in the table always becomes `0`.

I should note that everything works on both my local machine with `devMode` set to both `true/false` as well as on the staging server which is identical to the production server, yet somehow the production server does not work. `return $asset->id` on production returns the id, so I don't understand why `0` is saved to the db.

If I do

```
return $asset->id;
$ticket->assetId = $asset->id;
```

on production (with `devMode false`) as a test, it returns the correct id, however removing `return` and running again still saves `$ticket->assetId` as `0`.

I'm genuinely baffled by this.

When `devMode` is `false` no logs are produced when running the code.

Comment: Is the asset being saved correctly? On your ``saveElement`` call, change it to``$assetService = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);`` Then add something like ``if (! $assetService) { throw new \Exception("Couldn't save asset: " . print_r($assetService->getErrors(), true)); }``

Comment: Now I'm even more baffled. I used your code suggestion, no error was thrown and everything is working. However the only difference between your code and mine is that I had no exception included. So I reverted back to my code and it still works! (But I'm keeping your version with the exception for the future). I just don't understand why it wasn't working but is now.